# Folder name is not valid - error in SharePoint 2013 Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

When I try to open SharePoint 2013 On Prem site using SP Designer 2013 I am getting

> Folder name is not valid error

I tried these solutions from this link, but couldn't get it working.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/241d44f4-fb4e-4ce7-b134-72e0a7257a49/unable-to-open-sharepoint-site-with-designer-folder-name-is-not-valid?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct URL. Try the URL in Internet Explorer first.

Comment: I opened the site in IE and then copied the url into designer. The same problem exists.

Comment: I assume you didn't put the full url which include the page also.. Try only the siteurl instead

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes I tried with the site url.. Its the same behavior..